# In Quarkus the health check endpoints /q is appended automatically in url

Tags: quarkus

Recently i have upgraded to latest version of quarkus (version : 1.13.3.final) when ever loaded the
swagger URL its appended /q in url automatically for health check endpoints. Is there a way to disable appending /q in url itself for swagger and health points.

ex: health endpoint readiness : /health/ready
health endpoint liveness : /health/live
but it's appending extra /q in url due to that some logic is not working and can't add /q.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried 1.13.7.Final or 2.0.3.Final?

Comment: If we set like this in 1.13.3.final version will it work or have to upgrade 1.13.7.final ? and also 1.13.7.final is stable version?                                  quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/

Comment: 1.13.7.Final is of course a stable version

Comment: how we can get the application version in Quarkus i mean in Springboot will use /actuator/info to get the version details of application and what about in Quarkus?

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13598

Comment: please share any sample snippet of code to implement /q/info endpoint in Quarkus?

Answer (score 0):

As @geoand said, 1.13.7.Final or 2.0.3.Final are the most recent versions. But, to answer your question: In one of the releases, Quarkus introduced the `non-application-root-path` which distinguishes non-application endpoints like *metrics*, *health* or *openapi* from application endpoints (the ones you create).

[`non-application-root-path`](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.non-application-root-path) can be set via [configuration properties](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.non-application-root-path).

Comment: If we set like this in 1.13.3.final version will it work or have to upgrade 1.13.7.final ? and also 1.13.7.final is stable version? quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/ (any other config needs to set along with this property?)

Comment: 1.13.7.Final is the latest stable 1.x release, 2.0.3.Final is the latest stable 2.x release. 2.x introduces Vert.x 4 and a lot more improvements. You should try to upgrade. I've never set that property, but I guess that just changing `quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=${quarkus.http.root-path}` will do the trick. The docs also point that out, please see https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.non-application-root-path.